# How to increase/decrease the spaces before and after the basedescript environment?

Tags: spacing, basedescript

A minimal working sample is provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdwlist,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[6]
\begin{basedescript}{\desclabelstyle{\pushlabel}\desclabelwidth{6em}}
\item[ITEM 1] \lipsum[1]
\item[ITEM 12] \lipsum[2]
\item[ITEM 1234] \lipsum[3]
\end{basedescript}
\end{document}
```

The complied PDF is as follows.

[image]

My **QUESTION** is *how to increase/decrease the spaces before and after the basedescript environment?*

I read the `mdwlist` package but found no answer, so any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to set is `\topsep` (used on either end of the list)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdwlist,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[6]
\begin{basedescript}{%
  \desclabelstyle{\pushlabel}%
  \desclabelwidth{6em}%
  \setlength{\topsep}{20ex}% or whatever you prefer
}
\item[ITEM 1] \lipsum[1]
\item[ITEM 12] \lipsum[2]
\item[ITEM 1234] \lipsum[3]
\end{basedescript}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I suggest to use the `enumitem` package, as `mdwlist` has been abandoned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[6]
\begin{description}[
  align=left,
  leftmargin=6em,
  labelwidth=6em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  topsep=20ex,
]
\item[ITEM 1] \lipsum[1]
\item[ITEM 12] \lipsum[2]
\item[ITEM 1234] \lipsum[3]
\end{description}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And as a supplement, we can also change the items space in this way: `\setlength{\itemsep}{20ex}`.